# nodejs error javascript error: SyntaxError: Unexpected end of JSON input

Tags: javascript

Please, can i ask you, what means this error and how to fix it?
[..Here is image..](https://i.stack.imgur.com/ljRyX.png)

It's probably a problem with the port if I am not mistaken, but as regulated? I found nothing

Comment: The image you posted has no mention of a syntax error.

Comment: Image talks about a port being in use and your title is JSON??

Comment: In putty no, but on web it´s showing..

Comment: https://s22.postimg.org/fk1uyjbwx/Bez_n_zvu.png

Comment: So did you search stackoverflow for eaddrinuse 3001 and see what it says?

Answer (score 0):

Your http://localhost:3001 is already running, you are trying to run it again.